# Validate XML signature JAVA

Tags: java, xml, rsa, xml-signature

Is it possible to Validate following XML document:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
<DigestValue>DsP5NLca+plhp9tZvGwykfb2whQYt3CQ5sbsVd9Q9aE=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
LrfE0po3YPvVxB/m77iBWWiR07Ghiuhuj7tO2C2LKqZK2cLrAiidt+3tjbJ3m16quCFxfh7bmjRtJsGi7a3HKtK
qY4auqrjNB62AtYrxvm+7Qd/cRacom4e3M9uF9JD1zTfoGun9w4WDfDrDaoZ+ZwUgNtf6sTYO5Ctcj5sYcD0=
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyName>7D665C81ABBE1A7D0E525BFC171F04D276F07BF2</KeyName>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

The problem is when i run my code, this error appears

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: cannot find validation key
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature$DOMSignatureValue.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.validate(Unknown Source)
    at paket.XmlValidator.validate(XmlValidator.java:28)
    at paket.Test.main(Test.java:43)
Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.KeySelectorException: No KeyValue element found!
    at paket.KeyValueKeySelector.select(KeyValueKeySelector.java:47)
    ... 4 more
javax.xml.crypto.KeySelectorException: No KeyValue element found!
    at paket.KeyValueKeySelector.select(KeyValueKeySelector.java:47)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature$DOMSignatureValue.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.validate(Unknown Source)
    at paket.XmlValidator.validate(XmlValidator.java:28)
    at paket.Test.main(Test.java:43)
```

i have successfully validated the following XML with the same code:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>+uYi9GD7lNpk5+AZWjVylxm4PeKGXoFEalJPd44oMeg=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>Ov9TJmROGakTblMO8F2otx3YsmzY1N7tUEuJVauqP4EgePUtYpfMdiv1fKdZreeLyri7WRIOrxiq
mEJEWCmpzVKZypJ293y4STmRw4rfUgFQeaatj2AmK2q5zDaE9jzl6+HtiRgDykZpgx7DWC8MHydK
P8wnEHyn2ozYdqL0VCjRfk95zcm0jMknWmytippXf1bqufkhlOLdS46VGyvYM8ZAc742MN3QX1+I
SvNs1a+FNrgQwb0NaYLzX2hWOtFNo2ZparQXynfQy1jj6JHBRvmldLjHiI4nwYgtfEZL6Fgh/H6c
PSnM/Sd6hoh1B6zjhbIViqfaLKLkds/Et6WNYw==</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>xhbxdz2KP0/GwuoBuE2EfqoSUHj5nTZAC7c+UoUYtpqC8yRfe6BaFjdT/kWJNM8rZhJRawkh8qub
U4Iag0N1Cu8JNgOMXjeFJnVpa1HDijk9blQhLybGawh+TrC1v8D/9OGN5avkAjG/jpEFofOUpINp
Z2ThbhjgOzZV2kSa776nlwLhTLChf0iL5a78otVcDcuU8nmVkkhwFLbggbIRgdVFAk0bKFDYwWqw
kOmimDs2c7lLvu9n+X6IEFJLKt5YmKsBlhxx7LjvVih7vFc27+OtQpKw2EZjHPpmcP/qOEzESOCe
C8AHDrw3EWU5n1Bib8t8WteE5WPd2HbsJ86o3w==</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

What is the difference between this tow XML Signature, and why is it working on the second XML example and not on the first ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in first XML you are providing keyInfo with KeyName

```
<KeyInfo>
<KeyName>7D665C81ABBE1A7D0E525BFC171F04D276F07BF2</KeyName>
</KeyInfo>
```

and in second:

```
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>xhbxdz2KP0/GwuoBuE2EfqoSUHj5nTZAC7c+UoUYtpqC8yRfe6BaFjdT/kWJNM8rZhJRawkh8qub
U4Iag0N1Cu8JNgOMXjeFJnVpa1HDijk9blQhLybGawh+TrC1v8D/9OGN5avkAjG/jpEFofOUpINp
Z2ThbhjgOzZV2kSa776nlwLhTLChf0iL5a78otVcDcuU8nmVkkhwFLbggbIRgdVFAk0bKFDYwWqw
kOmimDs2c7lLvu9n+X6IEFJLKt5YmKsBlhxx7LjvVih7vFc27+OtQpKw2EZjHPpmcP/qOEzESOCe
C8AHDrw3EWU5n1Bib8t8WteE5WPd2HbsJ86o3w==</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
</KeyInfo>
```

Comment: The error is clearly saying no KeyValue element found _javax.xml.crypto.KeySelectorException: No KeyValue element found_. Hope that helps !

Comment: The Question is can it validated with only the KeyName Node.

Answer (score 1):

The KeyValueKeySelector won't help you here, as that signature contains no KeyValue.
You have to extend KeySelector and implement e.g. a KeyNameKeySelector that will look up the actual key in a KeyStore, based on the given KeyName. Provided you have that Key in that Keystore then, yes, you can verify that signature.

This should get you going: http://jirablog.blogspot.no/2007/11/xml-signature-pouzit-nebo-ne.html